# Cannot import .ics file events from email to iPhone calendar (iOS10.1.1)

Tags: iphone, calendar, ios, import

Unable to import events (36 total) from an .ics file I emailed to myself.  I used to see "Add All" as an option when viewining the .ics events. Now, all I see where "Add All" used to be is "Done".  If I tap any of the individual 36 events, I have an option to add to calendar as an individual event, but can no longer add numerous events from one .ics file with one click.

Not accusing, but, this seems to be occurring since updating to iOS 10.1.1. Anyone else experience this?

Answer (score 1):

Once imported iOS seems to remember the filename and hides "Add All" to prevent a second import (which would duplicate the events).

When you're sending yourself a new set of events, try using a different filename (add a timestamp or something similar).

(the same thing happened to me with a web generated set of events under iOS 9)

Comment: I just tried adding a date/time stamp to the file name, still no luck.  Any other ideas?

Comment: I found the solution from:  https://www.reddit.com/r/apple/comments/54m01w/with_ios_10_the_import_all_events_button_when/  

If you access your mail account from the Safari browser, open the .ics attachment the "Add All" option is displayed in the top right.